# How to parse a "Mysql result JSON String" in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Is there a way to convert it into object form? So that each field of the result can be accessed results[i].field
where i is the number of records in the mysql result..

This is my JSON String
http://pastebin.com/Cky1va3K

Answer (score 2):

Sure. That's what JSON is for, really; it stands for JavaScript Object Notation. A JSON object is a JavaScript object literal.

See the official JSON documentation on using JSON in JavaScript [here](http://www.json.org/js.html). Some browsers have native support for JSON parsing (so you don't have to use `eval()`) and for those that don't, a JavaScript JSON parser is available for download from that page.

Answer (score 0):

if you paste this string serverside into JavaScript code, it is converted automatically.

```
var myResult = { "result" : /* etc.*/ };
alert(myResult.result[0].REPORT); // see the result
```